# How to save Thread to SharedPreference Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, sharedpreferences

I have Bluetooth ConnectedThread from Android Documentation, and i want to save the value of an ConnectedThread variable to SharedPreference.
I have:

```
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
```

and the function head:

```
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread{
     public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType){
          }
    }

mConnectedThread = ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType)
```

What i need is to save `mConnectedThread` to SharedPreference.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

mConnectedThread value

```
Thread[Thread-16961,5,main]
```

Comment: Hi. Why do you want to save the value of ConnectedThread? That class is derived from Thread and if you call toString() function of the ConnectedThread it will just give you the name of the thread. Is this the value you want to store?

Comment: this is what i want to save, the value of mConnectedThread -> Added above. And after that i want to restore it still as a ConnectedThread Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `BaseActivity` and extend it in `Activity2`. Make `BaseActivity Abstract` and create a public static Thread TempThread = null; and save your thread there `BaseActivity.TempThread = mConnected`. Thank call it by `mConnectedThread = BaseActivity.TempThread;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of mConnectedThread and store it in SharedPreferences, you can do the following:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("Surface", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("ConnectedThread", mConnectedThread.toString());
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve the value of ConnectedThread from SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("Surface", MODE_PRIVATE);
String sTest = sharedPreferences.getString("ConnectedThread", "DefaultValue");
```

Comment: Crashes on `.setname()`
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at itbstudios.com.temperatureprobes.bluetooth.BluetoothCommunicationService.write(BluetoothCommunicationService.java:219)

Comment: can you please post you other source code and the Logcat? thanks.

Comment: I can't do that doing to a contract. But i can tell you how the module of the app works and what i am trying to do.
App Starts, you chose ann bluetooth device and conect. than from an other activity you write data via bluetooth to an arduino. The problem is that in secound activity i have to recall the class with the write function, which reinitialise ConnectedThread to null. Like no connection exists, even if i am connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save anything to shared preferences except strings.
It gets placed into a xml file, and the coding won't even allow for an array of strings.
You could try serializing it and putting it into a file

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to serialize?